# Differential equation problam

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been stuck trying to solve this particular ODE IVP 
which is:
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = 1+(t-y)^2, \qquad     t\in [2,3] \text{  and  }y(2)=1     $$

Thanks in advance 
:)

Answer (score 4):

Perform the substitution $z=y-t$. Then $\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dt} - 1$. The original ODE IVP becomes

$$ \frac{dz}{dt} + 1 = 1 + z^2 \implies \frac{dz}{dt} = z^2 $$

Which is a separable ODE and the rest should be simple.

Comment: Appreciated I got it thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=1+(t-y)^2=1+(y-t)^2\\ $$use this substitution $y-t=z$ so $$y'-1=z'\\y'=z'+1\\z'+1=1+z^2\\z'=z^2\\\frac{dz}{dt}=z^2\\\frac{dz}{z^2}=dt $$now : intergration $$\int_{0}^{t} \frac{dz}{z^2}=\int_{0}^{t}dt\\ \frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z_0}=t\\$$

Comment: Thank you so much I get it now :)